# When link clicked make a Div appear and save the hide/show options in $.cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

What i m trying to accomplish is when a link is clicked to make a div visible and make it remain there until its clicked no matter of window refreshes.Also save the show/hide options in a cookie

```
    < ahref="#">Home< / a>
    < div id="contentwrapper" style="display:hidden">
        holas
    < /div>

$(document).ready(function() {



 $('a').click(function(){

  $('#contentwrapper').fadeIn(300);        

  $.cookie('content','visible');
 var thecontent = $.cookie('content');

 });

 $('#contentwrapper').click(function(){
     $('#contentwrapper').fadeOut(100);
    $.cookie('content','hidden');

 });


 if ( thecontent == 'visible'){
   $('#contentwrapper').css("display","block");

  };
  if (content == 'hidden'){
   $('#contentwrapper').fadeOut(200);
  };

});
```

Comment: What's the problem? What isn't working?

Comment: On page refresh #contentwrapper redisappears.Witch makes me think that i have done something wrong with cookies.The other code is working properly.I have already included cookie plugin and i m using this code on a template for joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- There is no `display` type of `hidden` as you specify in `style="display:hidden"`, use `none` instead.
- When the page loads, `thecontent` variable is not defined in `if ( thecontent == 'visible'){` so change it to `if ( $.cookie('content') == 'visible'){`
- Same thing with the `hidden`: `if ($.cookie('content') == 'hidden'){`
- If you are using `fadeOut` etc. from jQuery, you should use `$('#contentwrapper').show();` instead of `$('#contentwrapper').css("display","block");`

all that:

```
$('a').click(function(){   
    $('#contentwrapper').fadeIn(300);        
    $.cookie('content','visible');
 });

 $('#contentwrapper').click(function(){
    $('#contentwrapper').fadeOut(100);
    $.cookie('content','hidden');
 });


 if ( $.cookie('content') == 'visible'){
   $('#contentwrapper').show();    
  };

 if ($.cookie('content') == 'hidden'){
   $('#contentwrapper').fadeOut(200);
 };
```

Comment: Well, display:hidden was typo.
I have tested this code on Fiddle and on localhost site.
On Fiddle ,when refresh cookie dont work while on localhost site nothing runs.Localy i have 2 scripts.1st one does some animation on header when i .click and the second one with a few changes was this one.Now ,after the changes, none script runs

Comment: Also when i remove the two if statements from the end the previus header script runs normally.

Comment: Strange.Identical code and cant get it running on my fiddle.(Is it cause of defferences between fiddles setting's?)

I have pasted and modified the code(just changed a class and added an animation for another element) to my localhost's script file.

When i click the link a page refresh starts witch hides contentwrapper again :/

Comment: please provide a link to your fiddle.

Comment: I deleted it few minutes ago.I think i forgot to load cookie plugin on fiddle.

The real problem now is that when i click a menuoption from my header i get a page refresh.And i get back to content area hidden :/

Comment: The content will restore the state from the cookie if you implement the same way as in my example.

Comment: So is there any correct way to acomplish this?I m using the code inside a joomla1.5 template