# jquery fadeout not a solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

With code below I'm fading some divs, but when I reload the page, the divs are visible again. I don't want that to happen; what I need is that if user clicks a back button or the home link, it should go back to the original format, otherwise the divs must be kept hidden when the page is reloaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#prodoneid").click(function () {
        $("#sliderid, .prodcls").fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

below is my html code

```
    <div id="prodoneid" class="prodcls"> <img src="images/zara/thumbnails/1.png" alt="ZARA"/> </div>

    <div id="prodtwoid" class="prodcls">
    <img src="images/zara/thumbnails/2.png" alt="ZARA"/>
    </div>

    <div id="prodthreeid" class="prodcls">
    <img src="images/puma/thumbnails/1.png" alt="PUMA"/>
    </div>

    <div id="prodfourid" class="prodcls">
    <img src="images/hermes/thumbnails/1.png" alt="HERMES"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: JS + cookies might be able to help you there

Comment: use a cookie. om nom nom

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524277/when-link-clicked-make-a-div-appear-and-save-the-hide-show-options-in-cookie

Answer (score 5):

You will have to save the fact that the divs are hidden either in a cookie or HTML5 local storage (newer browsers only) and process that saved information when the page loads in order to restore the page to the exact state you previously saved.  The browser does not do that for you.

Web pages are normally stateless on the client.  They are supposed to load from the server the same every time unless you design some client-side state into the page yourself.  So, if you want to create some client-side state, you have to either store that state on the server (often with ajax) and put that state back into the page when it's loaded again by that particular viewer.  Or, you have to save the state in the local browser (generally using cookies or HTML5 local storage), retrieve it from there when the page is loaded and act on it to put the page in the desired state.

Here's some pseudo code for using cookies for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* read the cookie "sliderHidden" and if it's is set to 1, 
        then: */
    $("#sliderid, .prodcls").hide(); 


    $("#prodoneid").click(function () {
        $("#sliderid, .prodcls").fadeOut(250);
        /* write a cookie called "sliderHidden" set to 1 
            that remembers that that these items are hidden */
    });
});
```

For jQuery, there is a [cookie plug-in](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) that makes it easy to read/write cookies.

Comment: dear greg what ur edited code is doing is first hiding the #slider and .prodcls as my #prodoneid is in the .prodcls then there is nothing to click

Comment: This is your own code from your question - you wrote it.  If you want to add your HTML to your question and describe what you want hidden, then we could advise on the proper jQuery to hide just what you want.

Comment: @sajid - What do you want to hide in that HTML?  What do you want to be clickable?

Comment: the .prdocls want to be clickable and the hiding the .prodcls + .slidercls

Comment: @sajid - where's the slidercls?  I don't see it in your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You *should* use `fadeOut`, but you should also use a technology such as cookies, or HTML5 localStorage if you want to be part of bleeding edge technology so you can *persist* the setting between page loads.

When you `fadeOut` the elements, you should write the state you choice of storage, and on page load you should check the storage to see if a previous state exists; and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) the div if necessary.

You can read more on [localStorage here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage), and [cookies here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie). A [jQuery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) exists which abstracts the low level cookie interface, and you may find it of interest.

Infact, your best option may be to look at [*this plugin*](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/localstorage), which attempts to use localStorage, but falls back to cookies if they are not supported in the current browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some kind of cookie to save 'hidden' status of the element. Look for jQuery cookie plugin (http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

Answer (score 0):

Hm- HTML is static!

I think you have got to handle this by a session (depends on the programm language) or cookie.

For the Cookie have a look at: [this tutorial](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using some kind of session state variable or cookie, that is a weak solution though. Your question is not very clear, better perhaps would be to reconsider the structure of your page and or the view model (assuming MVC here?)

Comment: If you want to provide a good answer, you could comment on the quest and ask your additional questions regarding the OP's exact need instead of asking in your answer. Just some friendly advice.